# App Store buttons in the ios7 world: still shiny?

Tags: app-store-connect

It appears the [Apple App Store badge and images](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/marketing/index.html) are still shiny. I assumed the reflections would go away after ios7 was formally released.

Has Apple announced if and when the buttons would change? I expect they would communicate on this since it's a very common marketing material that is substantially out of date with the new design.

Comment: Rather than bounce this off as primarily discussion / off topic - is there a practical question you are trying to get solved rather than just wanting to poll people to find out their opinions?

Comment: sorry, @bmike, by "has there been discussion" I meant "has Apple made an announcement about". I'll change the wording.

Comment: Let's see what voters say - it's still a yes / no question. You also didn't edit in the problem you face as a user of Apple product / service so people will likely have to guess if they want to try an answer.

Comment: I have never known Apple to make announcements about such things. If the shininess offends them then one day it will be silently replaced—providing headlines for "up to the minute" tech blogs. I'm following @bmike's lead for now, but my instinct would be *vote to close.*

Comment: I just wanted to get it over to StackOverflow if it's really a question only registered developers can answer. I can't log in and see what the @tedder42 is actually looking at, but since it's not code-level this might be the best place for the topic.

Comment: yeah, I know it's a weird stackexchange-style question. I'm okay with it being closed. Thanks for the feedback bmike and @jaberg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No change has been pre-announced (and that would be a surprise).

Furthermore, Apple's marketing guidelines have not changed the design of the badge and buttons in conjunction with iOS 7's release.

- https://developer.apple.com/app-store/marketing/guidelines/